# Typescript decorator to authenticate use of methods

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'd like to create a decorator that can be applied to methods,
It's goal is to control whether you're allowed to run a certain method or not.
Meaning it should have a certain condition, if it passes it'll run as usual (in the same context as well)

Here's a shot I took on this but **failed due to private members** the object has, and now had no access to when I ran the function:

```
return function(target:any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor){
    var funcToRun = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = () => {
        if(true) { //if has permissions
            return p.call(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't change the passed descriptor but instead would return a changed copy.

Here's a working version of what you asked for:

```
function deco(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const newDescriptor = Object.assign({}, descriptor);

    newDescriptor.value = function () {
        if (this.x > 0) {
            return descriptor.value.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`can't invoke ${ propertyKey }`);
        }
    }

    return newDescriptor;
}

class A {
    constructor(private x: number) {}

    @deco
    methodA() {
        console.log("A.methodA");
    }
}

let a1 = new A(10);
a1.methodA(); // prints: "A.methodA"

let a2 = new A(-10);
a1.methodA(); // throws error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20deco(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20newDescriptor%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20descriptor)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(descriptor)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20newDescriptor.value%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.x%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20descriptor.value.apply(this%2C%20arguments)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%60can't%20invoke%20%24%7B%20propertyKey%20%7D%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20newDescriptor%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%40deco%0A%20%20%20%20methodA()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22A.methodA%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%40deco%0A%20%20%20%20methodB()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22A.methodB%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Comment: here is the fixed playground tinyurl.com/y8q7hydj